# How to ask for more details about the job before applying?

Tags: software-industry, hiring-process, benefits

I was recently approached via linked-in from a company manager. He asked one of my contacts to introduce him to me on LinkedIn. I am currently working as Technical Java Architect.

Then He told me that he has a senior Java/JavaEE developer position. If you are interested, we can have a Skype interview.

Shouldn't I ask for more details about the role and salary and benefits too to decide should I apply there or not.

So for that purpose, what would be most appropriate text/question formation to ask more about my role, salary and other benefits.

Thanks.

Comment: `How to ask for more details about the job before applying?` - Why not just ask for more details about the job before applying?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know exactly what your questions are, but I think it's worthwhile to frame the upcoming conversation<sup>1</sup> (interview) in a way that's best for you.

You can respond to him and say something like this:

Thank you for your message. I would like to go forward and have a discussion. What time is best for you? I am usually free at [*and then list a few times*].

I have several questions, that I would like to discuss with you: [and then list them]: I would like to know more about your company, what position you're trying to fill, and about the salary/benefits<sup>2</sup>.

Looking forward to learning more about your company, and telling you more about myself.

Sincerely,

John Doe

1. He has just as much a responsibility to sell you on his company as you do to sell yourself as being a valuable employee deserving of a high salary.
2. Often people negotiating want the other party to give terms first. He may not want to state a precise salary before you do.

Answer (score 2):

I would simply send a mail requesting some more details. Also, talking with him on Skype would be a good way to get more information. If it turns out you are not interested in the job after that Skype talk, you have at least trained your interviewing skills a bit more.

Comment: I want to move once and stay there for a while. if there package is good, then i can join them, otherwise, if they are considering low salary, i am really not interested, that's why I wanted to know more details so that I can decide should I proceed or not.